# Hybrid Azure AD user password reset

Tags: azure, change-password

after more then three weeks of search, try and error I tumble back here for help.

I have successfully connected the on premise AD with the Cloud Azure AD and passwort sync seems to work as well. But at last there is still a problem present I just can't locate and/or fix. If a synced User trys to reset his password on the portal.office.com website (which should be forced after 90 days) he is forbidden to do so.

Now to my question: Is it true, that the only possible way to reset synced users password is for the admin manually reset the password in the locale AD?

Thank you very much.

Best regards
Sala

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reset synced passwords by users. It requires Azure AD Premium for appropriate users and several additional setup steps including Password Writeback feature enabled. See "Enable users to reset or change their AD Passwords" topic in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-passwords-getting-started/#enable-users-to-reset-or-change-their-ad-passwords) post.